# Overwriting default CSS and JS in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

How do I remove the current CSS files from CakePHP 3 and add my own?

I have removed these codes from `default.ctp`:

```
<?= $this->Html->css('base.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->css('cake.css') ?>
<?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
```

But still its showing the default CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP 3 the default install carries the full HTML document in `Templates/Pages/home.ctp`. Try to remove it there also.

Comment: thanks but it didn't worked i even removed the files from webroot folder of the app

Comment: sorry it worked there was some cache issue ctrl+F5 and it worked thanks